# How do I get to Alarms?

Tags: alarm

I know I can get to alarm setup through the Clock app, but I swear this used to be a separate app. How do you get directly to the Alarms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick look around shows that the Alarm function is most definitely part of the Clock app.

Answer (score 2):

I know that with [LauncherPro](http://www.launcherpro.com/) you can set up "actions" as shortcuts, rather than directly to apps.  You might be able to create a shortcut directly to the Alarm app.

There are probably other apps out there that do this.  I would be interested in the answer, as I have a similar gripe about all of the "sub apps" included with the Clock app.

Comment: You can indeed do this on LauncherPro. Long-press the homescreen and go to `Shortcuts`. From there go to `Activities` and it'll be under `Clock` -> `com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock`

Answer (score 1):

I set my alarms by tapping the Current Time on [Beautiful Widgets](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.levelup.beautifulwidgets). The "Beautiful Smaller Home Weather" widget takes up 4 slots on the home-screen but allows short-cuts to 3 actions: Set Alarms, Calendar, and Weather Forecast. The widget also lets you see the Current Time, Today's Date, and Current Weather with a glance at your home-screen.

[Beautiful Widgets](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.levelup.beautifulwidgets) has a 4.5 star rating from 22k+ ratings. It costs ~$2 but I am not alone in saying that it is worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

On my Droid X, there was an app preinstalled called "Alarm & Timer". That's what I've been using for alarms. Not sure if this is the same thing you are talking about though.

Which verison of the OS are you running? My Droid X is still on 2.1.

Comment: I'm running 2.2 unrooted on Droid v1. The "Alarm & Timer" app sounds familiar ... maybe it was removed in 2.2?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'll check my wifes Droid 2 when I get home and see if she has the Clock app instead of the Alarm & Timer.

Comment: Just checked my wife's Droid 2 running 2.2 - she has the "Alarm & Timer" app.